# How to insert an HTML object based on what text is inputted

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to put a way to easily insert GIFs/images into a webpage like the way Discord inserts images by text (i.e. `:gifname:`).

I assume it processes some `<textarea>`'s content and gets the name of the image, and then inserts it. How can I do this?

Can I do some sort of `replace()` insert abuse type thing, like:

```js
Text.replace(":example:", "<img src='imagepath.png'>")
```

Comment: How about just try it to see if "you can" do it or not? you can use sites like https://jsfiddle.net then you can share your code if you have any problem

Comment: Im guessing that he doesn't have a firm grasp of js yet.

Comment: @Hermanboxcar I can use javascript, I could figure that out and write it, but I didn't when I wrote it and I didn't want to waste time.

Comment: @Positivity ^^^^

Comment: @Michael Search, and research... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Positivity ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `input` or `textarea` tag are't possible.

Because these elements can handle only plain text like Ascii, UTF-8, and others. Emoji works in it because is part of the Unicode system.

In that way, u can do this as Hermanboxcar said above, replacing an string with another.

The way Discord works are more complex because it handles events and sub-nodes in DOM (Document Object Model).

You could look for WYSIWYG, it's the name of Discord's text field are using.

I recommend you inspect Discord in the browser and try to type anything else. You will see that it works in another way as you no expect

Answer (score 2):

Use js.

First, give your textarea an id attr:
`<textarea id="text"></textarea>`
then,

```
<script>
let t = document.getElementById('text')

function addShortcut(placeholder, emoji) {
  t.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    if(t.value.includes(placeholder)) {
      t.value = t.value.split(placeholder).join(emoji)
    }
  })
}

//examples:
addShortcut('hi', 'hello')
addShortcut(':shug:', '¯\\_(ツ)_/¯')
</script>
```

If you want to add a shortcut, just use `addShortcut` again after where I did.
you can delete the examples

Edit: made a typo, fixed it

Edit: If you want to have an image, then do something like this:

```
addShortcut(":gif:", "<img src='animation.gif' height='14px' width='auto'></gif>")
```

If you want to use a smaller text size, then just change the height attribute to match your text size.

Edit:

```js
let t = document.getElementById('text')

function addShortcut(placeholder, emoji) {
  t.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
    if (t.innerHTML.includes(placeholder)) {
      t.value = t.innerHTML.split(placeholder).join(emoji)
    }
  })
}

//examples:
addShortcut('hi', 'hello')
addShortcut(':shrug:', '¯\\_(ツ)_/¯')
addShortcut(':check:', '<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/10/01/49/hook-1727484_1280.png"></img>')
```

```css
textarea {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<textarea contentEditable="true" id='text' style='border: 1px solid #ccc;'>Hello</textarea>
```

Comment: How could I insert an image/file, though? And also, could you please edit and add tabs in your function so I can read it better?

Comment: I edited it. Sorry I'm such a bad formatter, my teacher emphasizes my non-existant tabs, but I am just too lazy to do it right. My code gets minified anyways

Comment: Also, if you need something like a shruggie, with a backslash, make sure to double backslash since \ is an escape character in js. \\ will just be one \

Comment: It did not work. Even when I set it to output to a `<p>` element it still didn't work. Edit: It can replace text (in the textarea), but not the image, which is what I wanted.

Comment: What @Michael is looking for, is how to add images on `input` or `textarea` tags

Comment: Its a weird thing, but only if you go, type the shortcut, and then click out of the textarea, then it will update. This does not work on inputs

Comment: try my example |

Comment: to actually achive it though, you would have to do some DOM manipulation, where first you use a contenteditable div instead of a textarea, and set a keydown on it, where the div is just a "decoy" for the user, and you store what the user types using the event listener. When the string the user types uses one of the set shortcuts, then the js text version will update to replace it, and then set the innerHTML of the div as the js text.

Answer (score -2):

To change source of image I would recommend selecting your image using query selector and then simply replacing it to other image

```
   <img class="example-image" src="./image.jpg" alt="">

   <script>
        document.querySelector('.example-image').src = 'image-replace.jpg';
   </script>
```

Have in mind that in shown example I used picture I already had on disc, but you can use url to image, and if you want to use textarea to get image path/url, here is the code to do so, it works on a button click:

```
   <img class="example-image" src="./image.jpg" alt="">
   <textarea class="example-textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
   <button class="example-btn">Click</button>

   <script>
           document.querySelector(".example-btn").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
            document.querySelector('.example-image').src = document.querySelector('.example-textarea').value;
        })
   </script>
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I asked for. I wanted it to trigger from depending on what some text in an input element was, and create an image.

Comment: What @Michael is looking for, is how to add images on `input` or `textarea` tags